# Passing a Struct Containing a Vector to a CUDA Kernel

Tags: c, struct, cuda

I have a large code that I need to pass a struct to a CUDA kernel that has a larger number of ints for parameters and a vector. I can't figure out how to pass the struct to the CUDA kernel. I've copied it to the device, but get the following error when trying to compile:

```
test_gpu.cpp:63:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void (*)(Test)' and 'dim3')
    computeTotal<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>(test_Device);
test_gpu.cpp:63:36: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('dim3' and 'Test *')
    computeTotal<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>(test_Device);
```

Attached is a small almost working example of the code, any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef struct Test{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    std::vector<int> vector;
    std::string string;
}Test;

Test test;

__device__ void addvector(Test test, int i){
    test.x += test.vector[i];
    test.y += test.vector[i+1];
    test.z += test.vector[i+2];
}

__global__ void computeTotal(Test test){
    for (int tID = threadIdx.x; tID < threadIdx.x; ++tID )
    addvector(test, tID);
}

int main()
{
    Test test_Host;
    int vector_size = 512;
    test_Host.x = test_Host.y = test_Host.z = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < vector_size; ++i)
    {
        test_Host.vector.push_back(rand());
    }

    Test* test_Device;
    int size = sizeof(test_Host);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&test_Device, size);
    cudaMemcpy(test_Device, &test_Host, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 dimBlock(16);

    dim3 dimGrid(1);

    computeTotal<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>(test_Device);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` can't be used in device code.  Are you compiling this code in a `.cpp` file?  CUDA device code normally belongs in a `.cu` file.

Comment: Yes, it's a large C++ code, using OpenMP and MPI on CPUs. I'm thinking I might have to pull out the vector from the structure and pass that as a pointer seperately.

Answer (score 2):

Items from C++ standard libraries aren't generally/normally usable in CUDA device code.  The documentation support for this is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-library).

For this particular case, it means you may have trouble with either `std::vector` or `std::string`.  One possible workaround is to replace these with ordinary C-style arrays:

```
#define MAX_VEC_SIZE 512
#define MAX_STR_SIZE 512

typedef struct Test{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int vec[MAX_VEC_SIZE];
    char str[MAX_STR_SIZE];
}Test;
```

This will of course necessitate changes elsewhere in your code.

Comment: ... and consider making those arrays pinned, i.e. allocated using `cudaMallocHost()`.